# Mathematic calculation using array of numbers and array of arithmetic operators in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have an array of n numbers and an array of n-1 operators. I must calculate the outcome, when each number will operate with the next one using an operator from the operator array. First I add the "+" operator in the operator array so that arrays are equal in size.

```
arrayOfOperators[0] = "+"
```

Then I applied the code bellow:

```
  if arrayOfNumbers.count == 0 {
    self.outcome = arrayOfNumbers[0]

    } else {

    for i in 0...arrayOfNumbers.count - 1  {


            if arrayOfOperators[i] == "+" {
                self.outcome = self.outcome + arrayOfNumbers[i]

            } else if arrayOfOperators[i] == "-" {
                self.outcome = self.outcome - arrayOfNumbers[i] 

            } else if arrayOfOperators[i] == "✕" {
                self.outcome = self.outcome * arrayOfNumbers[i] 

            } else {
                self.outcome = self.outcome / arrayOfNumbers[i] 

            }

        }

    }
```

With the code above I have the result that a calculator provides. My question is how the code should be if I need the result of a mathematic equation where multiplying/dividing must be applied first and then add/deduct the results to have the correct outcome. For example if

```
      numbers = [1,2,5,2,5,9]
      operators = [+, *, +, /, -]
```

My code will give ((1+2)*5+2)/5-2= 1,4 as a calculator would, but the equation would be
1+2*5+2/5-9=1+10+0,4-9=2,4. I tried many different loops but I could not make it.

Comment: ((1+2)*5+2)/5-9= -5,6 calculator correction

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54463146/1630618